# Qt: (error) undefined reference to QuaZip class (QuaZIP library)

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, quazip

I am trying to explore QuaZIP library in my Qt application. I put the quazip.h include in mainwindow.h and in mainwindow.cpp (I get the includes by auto-completion so they are right in regard to subfolders), I put quazip.h among headers in the PRO file. But if I try to consume the QuaZip class in mainwindow code I get "undefined reference to" errors when building.
What is the problem?

Edit: there is also a "error: undefined reference to `gzopen'" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to link against the library in your .pro file:

```
LIBS += -lquazip -lz
```

Answer (score 0):

Iget error: cannot find -lquazip. I add sources as .pri file.